# CakePhp: Got erros in response body when calling an API with the CakePHP HttpClient

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api, cakephp

I'm having some HTML text in my response from an API.

Response I got

[image]

Preview's response

[image]

Here is my code (PHP):

```
    public function getBeatmapInformations() {
    $this->render(false);
    if($this->request->is('get')){
        $url = $_GET['beatmapUrl'];
        $isOsuUrlBeatmap = "#^(?:https://)?osu\.ppy\.sh/(?:b|beatmapsets)/(\d*)#";
        if(preg_match($isOsuUrlBeatmap, $url, $matches)){
            $OSU_API_KEY = "MY_API_KEY";
            $httpClient = new Client();
            $response = $httpClient->get('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps', [
                    's' => intval($matches[1]),
                    'k' => $OSU_API_KEY
                ]
            );
            $result = $response->body();
            if(!empty($result)){
                echo $result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript side (AJAX request):

```
function launchAjaxRequest(beatMapUrl) {
let url = beatMapUrl.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
$.get({
    type : "GET",
    url: '/ofv/getBeatmapInformations',
    data: {
        beatmapUrl : url,
    },
    success: function(data){
       fillModesAvailablesForBeatmap(data);
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not manually echo anything in your controllers actions in CakePHP. The way to achieve json output in CakePHP is to use Data Views with Request Handler:

1.Enable Request Handler in your controller's initialize() method:

```
public function initialize(){
    $this->loadComponent("RequestHandler");
}
```

2.In your action, set your data to be serialized:

```
$result = $response->body();
$this->set(compact("result"));
$this->set("_serialize", "result");
```

More about Request Handler and Data Views can be found in docs: [JSON and XML views](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)

As probably someone will point it out, you have also an alternative here: you can simply stop execution of script right after echoing data with die(). But it is not the Cake way of handling this.

Comment: Thanks, The last solution you provided is working, I know this is a dirty way, but at least it's working as it should.